# How I can pass OS value to sql

Tags: shell, scripting, operating-system, sqlplus

I am trying to write a shell scripts for changing the db link as everytime password for Dev got change
so I am putting like below.

=======================================
export DEV_PASS=nevert3ll
sqlplus /nolog
connect apps/appspwd@TEST
drop database link TEST_TO_DEV;
create database link TEST_TO_DEV connect to apps identified by ${DEV_PASS} using 'DEV';
exit
EOF

=======================================
but this is treating ${DEV_PASS} a value rather than export value.

Can you advise me how to solve this issue.

Thanks,SM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing `-s` switch in `sqlplus`:

```
export DEV_PASS=nevert3ll
sqlplus -s /nolog
connect apps/appspwd@TEST
drop database link TEST_TO_DEV;
create database link TEST_TO_DEV connect to apps identified by $DEV_PASS using 'DEV';
exit
EOF
```

Comment: I am cloning a env where I will test it , I will update it another 1-2 hrs . Thanks SM

Comment: Thanks Anubhava , it is solved the issue. Thanks for your quick response. Thanks,SM